# File Download using physical file location onclick in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, download, onclick

I am facing a issue where am passing my file path in `href` and `onclick` the file is not downloaded and it shows file failed to download

Code:

```
  <a class="linkTagCSV"  href="path" download  >file</a>
```

Any suggestions would be great help.

Answer (score 1):

Set target with anchor tag,

```
<a download href="path" target="_blank">Click here to download package</a>
```

Comment: Hi Hari,   I tried that too but thats still failed to download

Comment: Hi, the problem was solved actually the file download from localhost is not allowed due to some security reasons  but when I tried to give location of s3bucket in href it worked.